# Putting mechanism in-between multiple implementations of the abstract class

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, polymorphism, decoupling

I am working in .NET 4.5 WPF application I have 3 views that are using containers with questions. 2 views have one set of questions and I am now working on adding another one that has 2 containers of questions as it is for two customers at once.

Class structure:

QuestionItem that is any question that is placed into the viewModel.

```
public abstract class QuestionItemViewModel : ValidatingScreen, IHandle<ValidatingEventArgs>,
    IEquatable<QuestionItemViewModel>{
public event QuestionAnsweredEventHandler AnsweredHandler;
public abstract string GetQuestionAnswer();
public abstract bool HasAnswer { get; }
public virtual void OnAnswered(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.AnsweredHandler != null)
            this.AnsweredHandler(this, e);
    }
}
```

then 4 types of questions, I am going to show 1 to save space but they all look the same.

Concrete implementation of question that is placed into viewModel (this is dropdown)

```
public class QuestionDropDownViewModel : QuestionItemViewModel, IEquatable<QuestionDropDownViewModel>
{
public string SelectedAnswer
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._selectedAnswer.IsNullOrEmpty())
                this._selectedAnswer = this.QuestionAnswerList.FirstOrDefault();

            return this._selectedAnswer;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._selectedAnswer != value)
            {
                this._selectedAnswer = value;

                if (this._isInitialised)
                {
                    this.IsDirty = true;
                    this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedAnswer);
                    this._eventAggregator.Publish(new QuotePropertyChangedEvent(true));
                    this.OnAnswered(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override string GetQuestionAnswer()
    {
        return this.SelectedAnswer;
    }

    public override bool HasAnswer
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedAnswer) && this.SelectedAnswer != "please select an item"; }
    }
```

in two views that have one set of questions `QuestionItemViewModel` are being placed in  `this.QuestionItems = new CustomerQuestionCollection(){CustomerId = this.CurrentTransactionDetail.TransactionMain.CustomerID};`.
Since view I am working on must have 2 collections there's additional collection `this.QuestionItemsForSecondCustomer = new CustomerQuestionCollection() {CustomerId = this.CurrentTransactionDetail.TransactionWill.SecondCustomerId};`

Questions are not being asked all at once but rather when question is answered `dropdownQuestion.AnsweredHandler += Quesion_AnsweredHandler;` is being fired on viewModel to look for next question based on previous answer.

```
protected override void Quesion_AnsweredHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var questionViewModel = sender as QuestionItemViewModel;
        if (questionViewModel != null)
        {
            this.EvaluateAndAddNextQuestion(questionViewModel);
            this.NotifyParent();
        }
    }
```

**The problem:** to start filling in second container I am checking if last question of first container has been answered and if it is I switch to second container

```
private void EvaluateAndAddNextQuestion(QuestionItemViewModel questionViewModel)
    {
        var collectionToBeFilled = this.IsWifForSecondCustomerVisible
            ? this.QuestionItemsForSecondCustomer
            : this.QuestionItems;

        this.ClearNextQuestions(collectionToBeFilled, questionViewModel);

        if (!(questionViewModel is QuestionDropDownViewModel) || (questionViewModel.HasAnswer))
        {
            this.AddNextQuestion(collectionToBeFilled, questionViewModel);
        }

        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsVisibleQuestionItemsForSecondCustomer);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => QuestionItems);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => QuestionItemsForSecondCustomer);
    }
```

however after I started filling in `QuestionItemsForSecondCustomer` if first container(`QuestionItems`) then gets modified I am unable to tell if it was the item from first or second container that fired `Quesion_AnsweredHandler`. This requires me to introduce some coupling between container and item inside container, loosest in my eyes is introducing `CustomerId` to `QuestionItemViewModel`, as I have `CustomerId` in container already and could identify if it was question from `this.QuestionItems` or `this.QuestionItemsForSecondCustomer`.

**Question:** Is there a way to introduce additional class out of `QuestionItemViewModel` like `CustomerQuestionItemViewModel` (or some other mechanism) that would have `CustomerId` that could sit inbetween 4 types of questions (`QuestionDropDownViewModel`,`QuestionRadioGroupViewModel`,..) that would not require me to make duplicates of those 4 classes e.g `QuestionDropDownViewModel` to `CustomerQuestionDropDownViewModel` but would still allow me to have `CustomerId` on them.

Immediate solution would be to add `CustomerId` to `QuestionItemViewModel` but it would leak the implementation of submechanism that doesn't belong here to base class, which I would like to avoid. Question is complicated if some part is unclear please let me know I will do my best to add missing detail.

Comment: why is there a (getter) property call SelectedAnswer and a method GetQuestionAnswer() seems like a code smell

Comment: @AwkwardCoder `SelectedAnswer` is dropdown specific property that is bound to View, every flavour of `QuestionItemViewModel` has one. `GetQuestionAnswer()` is mechanism that allows to get answer from any type of question being answered (for matching purposes mainly). How is this relevant?